# Horror of versioning MS Word files

Tags: git, ms-word, pandoc

Faced with an unfortunate need to version MS Word documents I have implemented the following configuration

#### `~/.gitconfig`

```
# Help MS Word document versioning
[diff "pandoc"]
    textconv=pandoc --to=markdown
    prompt = false
```

#### `./repo/.gitattributes`

```
# Version control MS Word
*.docx diff=pandoc
*.docm diff=pandoc
```

## Problem

When I try to run `git diff Big-Problematic-Document.docm`

```
19:17 $ git diff Big-Problematic-Document.docm
UTF-8 decoding error in /var/folders/7x/kwc1y_l96t55_rwlv35mg8xh0000gn/T//uPSuEc_Big-Problematic-Document.docm at byte offset 22 (c1).
The input must be a UTF-8 encoded text.
fatal: unable to read files to diff
```

### Diagnosis

- I understand that `pandoc` converted that thing and kept some non-UTF-8 encoded text

## Question

Is there a way to further develop `~/.gitconfig` so the `pandoc` conversion will remove non-UTF-8 text?

Answer (score 1):

seems that `pandoc` does not know how to treat **`.docm`** (Word w/ VB macros).
Give him an help and add the `--read=docx` explicit hint that the input is in fact a Word doc(x).

Probably you want to add that to the `docm` line in your `.gitattributes`.

That cures it for `pandoc 2.9.1.1`